# There was an error running the selected code generator: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object at

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

When trying to add a controller using Visual Studio , you may get the following error:

There was an error running the selected code generator: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.b__6_0()

Answer (score 4):

One reason is a bad package in the local nuget cache.
Clearing out the local nuget cache solves this problem.

For more info, see [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1923) issue.

If that doesn't work, try the following:

```
dotnet tool uninstall -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I cleared the cache and restart but ...nothing.

Comment: Did you have a preview SDK installed? If so, you need to uninstall.